# Do datastore delete commands count as write operations?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I needed to rebuild a database and noticed that my write operations were extremely high after I deleted a database kind. Do those count as write operations?

Comment: Remember all the indexes the entity was indexed by, also have to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a separate line for deleting entities in App Engine's Datastore pricing:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/pricing

Answer (score 0):

**This changed as of July 1st, 2016.**

Deletes now count against "Entity Deletes" rather than writes. They are also much cheaper at $0.02 per 100,000 entities.

We have a [pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/pricing) that explains it.